# Temperature Diffusion, Laplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Find the temperature field, given that the temperature satisfies $\nabla^2 T = 0$, and T is a function only of r (working in cylindrical polars)

I'm assuming I'm supposed to solve the Laplacian. So I've solved this and got T=A.ln r + B
Is this the temperature field or do I have to do something else?

Comment: You need boundary conditions.  Missing this, you need the full expression for the solution of the steady-state equation, which takes the form $$A \log{r} + B + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ C_n r^n + d_n r^{-n}\right ] e^{i n \theta} $$  If in fact you are $\theta$ independent, then you are OK, but still need BC's.

Comment: Solving for the boundary conitions isn't a problem, but I wasn't sure I had the right temperature field. Are C and D further constnts? Can you provide more information of how you got these?

Comment: These are obtained through solution of Laplace's equation via separation of variables.  $C$ and $D$ are constants determined from the boundary conditions, analogous to Fourier coefficients in a Fourier series.

Comment: Oh right yes I am $\theta$ independent, so now I just need to solve for the BCs

Answer (score 0):

In two dimensions, you fit $A\ln r+B$ to the boundary conditions (whatever they may be).

In three dimensions, you would do the same with $Ar^{-1}+B$. In general, it's $Ar^{2-n}+B$ in $n\ge 3$ dimensions.

By the way, an easy way to see that any radial solution ($T=T(r)$) of $\nabla^2 T  =0$ has to be of the above form is to consider the flux of gradient across the sphere of radius $r$. For a harmonic function, the flux must be independent of $r$. Hence, $r^{n-1}T'(r)$ is constant, which after integration gives the above.